# call method when program exits - onDestroy not reliable

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, ondestroy

I want to execute some functions when the program is exited by hitting the back button.
This is now done by onDestroy() which works in every case but one. When coming back from another activity in some cases on exiting the program, onDestroy is not called.

I know that in theory onDestroy should only be called when Android closes the app due to low memory, but for me, onDestroy works always and only in a very special case it does not.

Using onPause or onStop does not work because I only want to call the function when the program is exited but not when just another activity is called.

So is the last way to catch the back-button-click and call the function there? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: What are you trying to do on exit?  Also, you say "but for me, onDestroy works always..." Be careful not to make assumptions based on your anecdotal experience.  Make sure you understand the guarantees given by the lifecycle, and only assume that those are true.

Answer (score 10):

Tactically, use `onBackPressed()`.

Strategically, reconsider your architecture. A well-written activity should not care if `onDestroy()` is called, as it is guaranteed to NOT always be called. For example, Android can terminate your process whenever it wants (e.g., extreme low memory conditions). The fact that you need `onDestroy()` to work reliably suggests there are problems that should be resolved.

Comment: Isn't that overriding the back button? I think I read somewhere developers should avoid doing that.

Comment: @semajhan: Well, if you chain to the superclass, it will still do normal BACK behavior. But, yes, in general, developers should avoid doing that.